# How to use a CASE expression to match multiples rows in Google Data Studio (SQL/Big Query data set)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, case, looker-studio

I have a BigQuery table that contains a column which has a list of 'categories' (delimited by " / "):

```
  {
    "ID": "452",
    "Location": "France",
    "Calories": "400",
    "Categories": "/ brown / nutty / salty /"
  },
  {
    "ID": "288",
    "Location": "UK",
    "Calories": "800",
    "Categories": "/ brown / roasted / nutty /"
  },
```

I connect to my table using the following SQL query within Google Data Studio:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
ID,
Location,
Calories,
Categories
FROM table_name;
```

I am trying to group rows in the table by 'Categories'.

I should then be able to filter the rows by a category and the metrics can be averaged. In the example above, if I filtered by 'Nutty', the average 'Calories' would be '600'.

The CASE expression I have tried only allows me to match the last 'Category' within the Category column, rather than matching to all rows that include the string:

```
CASE
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Categories, '.*nutty.*') THEN 'Nutty'
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Categories, '.*brown.*') THEN 'Brown'
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Categories, '.*salty.*') THEN 'Salty'
END
```

I believe this is an aggregation issue, but is there any way to allow each row to be matched within a 'Category' dimension multiple times in this way?

Any help much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Case _expression_, not _statement_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `CASE` in your use-case is not practical - instead you should use `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL()` or `SPLIT()` along with `UNNEST()` as below example shows (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```sql
 #standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.your_table` AS (
  SELECT "452" ID,"France" Location,400 Calories,"/ brown / nutty / salty /" Categories
    UNION ALL
  SELECT "288","UK",800,"/ brown / roasted / nutty /"    
)
SELECT ID, Location, Calories, Category
FROM `project.dataset.your_table`, 
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(Categories, r' (\w+) ')) Category
```

this will give you below result

```sql
Row ID  Location    Calories    Category     
1   452 France      400         brown    
2   452 France      400         nutty    
3   452 France      400         salty    
4   288 UK          800         brown    
5   288 UK          800         roasted  
6   288 UK          800         nutty
```

Now, you can `GROUP BY` whatever logic you want and all Categories will be accounted appropriatelly

Comment: I don't understand why this is better than the first answer? Open to why this may be the case though?

Answer (score 1):

Data here looks like:

- views: 349493
- tags: "javascript|html|css"

Solution: `JOIN` to `SPLIT(tags) tag`, `GROUP BY tag`.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT SUM(view_count) views, tag
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions`, UNNEST(SPLIT(tags,'|')) tag
)
GROUP BY tag
ORDER BY 1 DESC
LIMIT 10
```

[image]